# media player in windows phone 7 displaying next song

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player

I want to do something similar to the media player in windows phone 7 where the next several song is shown. What approach I would take to accomplish this?

Example:
previous song
previous song
CURRENT SONG
next song
next song

my code currently like this:

```
        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)         
    {         
        List<string> songlist = new List<string>();         
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();         
        mySongCollection = library.Songs;         
        MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_ActiveSongChanged);         
        MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged);         

        UpdateCurrentSongInformation();         
    }         

    void UpdateCurrentSongInformation()         
    {         
        try         
        {
            MediaLibrary lb = new MediaLibrary();
            int i = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSongIndex;

           textBlock1.Text= lb.Songs.ToString();

            txtAlbumName.Text = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Album.Name;         
            txtArtistName.Text = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Artist.Name;         
            txtSongName.Text = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Name;
            progressBar1.Maximum = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Duration.Minutes*60+MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Duration.Seconds;
            double max = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Duration.Milliseconds;


            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();         
            bmp.SetSource(MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Album.GetAlbumArt());

            imgAlbumCover.Source = bmp;         
        }         
        catch         
        {         
            imgAlbumCover.Source = null;         
        }         
    }
```

Like Dennis suggest, I code it like this:

```
            MediaLibrary lb = new MediaLibrary();
            int i = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSongIndex;
            NextSong.Text = lb.Songs[i+1].Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSongIndex`, you can also access existing items in the queue by their index through `MediaPlayer.Queue[n]` where **n** is the song index. You will get a `Song` instance with the same metadata. As long as you have the current index, you can decrement it by one to check for the previous song, and increment it by one to check for the next song.