# How to get the MediaPlayer Queue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, media-player

In my application I am using the `MediaPlayer` to play a selection of songs, however it would be good to be able to get the songs that are going to be played next and display them to the user, either for information, or so they can jump several songs in the queue.

So how can I get a list of the Songs that are coming up in the `MediaPlayer` queue?
So that I can have a list of them which can be displayed to the user, in some sort of container, probably a `ListBox`.

I have tried using `MediaPlayerQueue` however this operator doesn't seem to have any form of functionality?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[media player in windows phone 7 displaying next song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907081/media-player-in-windows-phone-7-displaying-next-song)

```
MediaPlayer.Queue[n]
```

will give you the required **Song** instance

Comment: That pretty much does the job, but it would be good to be able to get the whole list of songs in the queue (the album), as I don't know how many songs there are I'd run into an error with certain index values

Comment: do you want a list of songs in the queue or a list of all the songs in the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. It work for wp8.1 silverlight.

> SongModel is my custom class

```
App.Handler.MediaPlayerQueqeLists = new ObservableCollection<SongModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < MediaPlayer.Queue.Count; i++)
{
  App.Handler.MediaPlayerQueqeLists.Add(new SongModel
  {
      Index = i,
      Title = MediaPlayer.Queue[i].Name,
      Artist = MediaPlayer.Queue[i].Artist.Name,
     StringDuration = (new DateTime(MediaPlayer.Queue[i].Duration.Ticks)).ToString("mm:ss")
  });
}
llsPlaylist.ItemsSource = App.Handler.MediaPlayerQueqeLists;
```